# Facebook API Graph: "upload video" after deprecation of publish_actions

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

i am struggling with new FB graph api v3.0.
The main purpose of my app is to upload video from my web server to user profile using  POST /me/videos.

```
FB.api(
            "/me/videos",
            "POST",
            {
                "file_url": <urlVideo>,
                "access_token": <access_token>
            },
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {

            alert("Congratulations! your video has been uploaded on your profile. ");
        }


    }
    );
```

This was achieved with *publish_actions* permission.
How can I use this code with api v3.0, without this permission?

From documentation it states that *publish_actions* has been replaced with share widows, but I guess is not the correct solution to upload a video..

Anyone can help me??
Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: as of now, it´s just not possible.

Comment: @luschn that means that my app after 1st of August just won't work?
I can't upload video on facebook profile anymore?

Comment: yes, that´s pretty much it.

Comment: [Changelog says regarding the Live API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#live-api-4-24), _“In the coming weeks, a new permission model that allows apps to publish Videos to their User's Groups and Timelines will be announced.”_ - my guess is that this probably won’t be limited to Live Videos, but will apply to normal videos as well. But nothing new has been announced in that regard yet as far as I know, so for now it’s just _wait & see …_

Comment: @CBroe thanks! What LIVE API states is not totally clear! They mention only live videos rather then standard video upload. At the moment I requested ‘publish_video’ permissions just in case, even tho it does not look linked with my use case.